# Using HTML Template with django project

Tags: html, css, django, templates

The problem I have is that I cant load pictures and CSS from template to django.
Here is the structure of the files.

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
[![enter image description here][5]][5]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Electro - HTML Ecommerce Template</title>

    <!-- Load static files -->

    <!-- Google font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>

    <!-- Slick -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/slick.css' %}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/slick-theme.css' %}"/>

    <!-- nouislider -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/nouislider.min.css' %}"/>

    <!-- Font Awesome Icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">

    <!-- Custom stlylesheet -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="{% static 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js' %}"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: yeah but it is showing me some errors and it doesnt wanna post it

Comment: In the debug screen there is a button "switch to copy-paste mode" or something that allows copying the error as raw text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `STATIC_URL` variable in `settings` and load it in html file.

Follow this documentation link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/ for more information.

Comment: STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

I put this inside settings.py

And it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

set static path in the settings.py

```py
STATIC_URL = '/main/main/static/'
```